# Less extend multipling class names

Tags: css, less

I've a generic class like:

```
button {
  color: dimgray;

  & > * {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
```

So i'm trying a simple extend:

```
button.new {
  &:extend(button all);
  color: green;

  &:hover {
    color: darkgreen;
  }
}
```

Why i've a .new.new select in extended class?

```
button,
button.new {
  color: dimgray;
}
button > *,
button.new > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
button.new {
  color: green;
}
button.new:hover,
button.new.new:hover {
  color: darkgreen;
}
```

This is not correct i think, i'm using last version of less (js library)

```
button.new.new:hover
```

Comment: Do you need the `all` keyword, because in this simple example you don't, and it will work correctly without `all`. Apparently it thinks that `:extend(button all)` means you also want to extend the `button.new` selector.

Comment: According to the documentation, I think it's normal: http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature

Comment: Yes, the double `.new` is there because `all` makes the `button.new` to also extend `button` in `button.new:hover` (thus `button.new` + `.new:hover` = `button.new.new:hover`)... it's really *all* :) I'm afraid the only easy workaround to get rid the doubles (not counting dropping `all`) would be an extra *differently-named* ruleset (to get rid of the name overlapping).

Comment: E.g. something like [this](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22button%2C%20nottub%20%7B%5Cn%20%20color%3A%20dimgray%3B%5Cn%20%20%26%20%3E%20*%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20display%3A%20inline-block%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20vertical-align%3A%20middle%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnbutton.new%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%26%3Aextend(nottub%20all)%3B%5Cn%20%20color%3A%20green%3B%5Cn%20%20%26%3Ahover%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20color%3A%20darkgreen%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D). (well, `.button`, `#button` or `button_` instead of `nottub` will do the trick too of course).